# invisible syntax error in code

Tags: ruby, syntax

I keep getting syntax errors at line 23, 28, and at the end of my program
at line 23 it says that the elsif statement is unexpected and doesn't belong there
at line 28 it says that the end statement is not needed
and at the end of my program it says that I'm missing an end statement

I don't think that I have any syntax errors, so if someone could help me spot my mistake that'd be much appreciated
Thanks :D

```
def get_last_date(strt,usage_list)
    if usage_list.empty?
        return "chemical left over"
    end

    date_list=[]
    for occurrence in usage_list
        if occurrence[0] != 0
            date_list+=[occurrence[2]]
        end
    end

    currdate=datelist.min                                       # this gets the earliest start date out of all the recurring uses
    lastuse=currdate

    while true                                                  # this loop is a loop for each day and each iteration icrements the currentdate by 1
        y=0
        usinglist=[]
        for recursion in usage_list                             # gets the recurring uses that have end_dates that are after the currdate and start_dates before the currdate
            if (recursion.length==4) &(recursion[3]< currdate)  # deletes a recurring use from the list of recurring uses if its past its end_date
                usage_list.delete_at(y)
                y--
        ****line 23**** elsif recursion[2] >= currdate
                usinglist+=[recursion]
            end

            y++
    *****line 28**** end

        used=false
        if usinglist.empty?
            return "chemical left over"
        end

        for uses in usinglist
            if uses[1]==0                                       # if its a daily periodicity subtract the amount from the total
                strt=strt-uses[0]
                used=true
            elsif uses[1]==currdate.cwday                       # if the periodicity day matches the current workday then subtracts the amount for weeky periodicity cases
                strt=strt-uses[0]
                used=true
            end
        end

        if strt==0                                              # if the chemical has been used up return either currdate or last use date appropriately
            return currdate
        elsif strt<0
            return lastuse
        end

        if used                                                 # sets the last used date to the current date if you used some of the chemical today
            lastuse=currdate
        end
        currdate=currdate+1                                     # increment currdate DateTime object
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
y--
y++
```

These statements don't exist in Ruby. Change them to

```
y -= 1
y += 1
```

respectively.

Also, you seem to be using `&` instead of `&&` on line 20.

Comment: thanks that was it, this answer is perfect.